# Turtles in sub-samples which make different actions

Tags: netlogo

I would need to let my agents/turtles to make some actions. Specifically I would like to select, let's say, 40 turtles and let make randomly some actions, for instance:

- 25 turtles action1;
- 15 turtles action2.

25, 15 should be randomly chosen.
I wrote the following

```
ask up-to-n-of num_of_turtles_per_tick turtles with [breed = M] [
         ifelse random-float 1 < prob
           [
           action1]
           [action2]
      ]
```

`prob` is set to `0.5`. I think that my code let 40 turtles to do either action1 or action2, with no possibility to distinguish between two sub-sample of turtles (25,15 in the example, or 20,20, or 12 and 18...).
I should probably add a new parameter to determine this randomly numbers and let them make separately actions.

Could you please give me some advice on how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the subsets to be mutually exclusive, so you need some construction that has an if-else type logic. But you can do either as a group or individually.

Individually is easier to understand, so let's start there (not tested so may have syntax errors). Basically you draw a random number and do one action if it's low and the other if it's high.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 40 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse random-float 1 < 15 / 40
    [ set color blue ]
    [ set color red ]
  ]
end
```

For the group approach, you need some way to remember the group that does the first action so you can identify all the others to be in the group that does the second action. The `member?` reporter checks whether a turtle is a member of the specified turtleset.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 40 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  let type1 n-of 15 turtles        ; assigns some to a temporary agentset
  ask type1 [ set color blue ]
  ask turtles with not member? self type1 [ set color red ]   ; gets the others
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much JenB for your help. Just one question on this: should I still consider `ask up-to-n-of num_of_turtles_per_tick turtles with [breed = M]`  or should I just include `ask turtles
  [ ifelse random-float 1 < 15 / 40`?

Comment: I don't actually know what you're asking. The `up-to-n-of` selects an initial group of turtles and the `ifelse` pushes them toward one action or another. Your question was about the splitting into two actions and that's what my answer is about. But looking at it again, are you asking how to select a probability?

Comment: What I would need to do is to select a maximum number (e.g. 40) of turtles that can make different actions (action1 or action2). Some of these turtles could make action1 with a certain probability, and the remaining could be make action2. I would prefer to not let all the turtles do the same action.

Comment: Both your code and my code have some of the turtles doing one thing and the other turtles doing a different thing. You need to explain what the code is doing that is different from what you want.

Comment: The code that I showed is selecting some turtles (up-to 40) from all the turtles I am considering (100) at some point in time. However, I would like that some percentage of that 40 turtles can do an action (action1) and the remaining can do action2.

Comment: That is exactly what your code is already doing. It takes 40 turtles, then has (approximately) 20 of them do one thing and the other 20 do the other thing. If you want it to be 15 and 25, then use probability of 15/40 instead of 0.5. If you want it to be exactly 15 then use `n-of` instead of random. I still don't understand your problem. You need to explain exactly what it is doing, what you want it to do, and what is the difference between those two things.

Comment: I thought it was wrong my approach and that all the turtles selected were doing the same action, or action1 or action2 with prob 0.5.